# How to test whether my tail is posixly correct?

Tags: posix, tail, busybox, mobaxterm

I'm having problems with a vim interface for the theorem prover HOL:

https://github.com/HOL-Theorem-Prover/HOL/tree/master/tools/vim

I run it on MobaXterm, a cygwin-based system, and vim is freezing when I do `hs` for sending a line to the theorem prover. MobaXterm implements much of basic commands through Busybox and I already had a problem because of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097775/compiling-poly-ml-on-mobaxterm-the-ar-u-option

The above hol-vim page says that the interface works with a posixly correct tail. This might be the source of the mentioned error. How can I test whether the `tail` command implemented by MobaXterm's Busybox is posixly correct?

Answer (score 2):

Failing there being an actual test suite to exercise POSIX conformance of tail, the best way is to read [the POSIX documentation for tail](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/tail.html) and see if your version matches up.

That said, I would be surprised if busybox `tail` is POSIXly correct -- busybox strongly optimises for size rather than total standards conformance in its exported interface. For example, it only has `-c` if `FEATURE_FANCY_TAIL` is enabled at compile time, which if you're optimising for size, it won't be: https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/tail.c#n28

Comment: My educated guess is that this whole POSIX conformance thing is a complete red herring and the real problem is the FIFO and output buffering.

Comment: @JdeBP What can I do to make the FIFO and output buffering work?